# Suricatta daemon mode: No suitable .swu image found

Tags: yocto, swupdate, eclipse-hawkbit, hawkbit

I'm trying to use hawkbit + swupdate to update my embedded linux system, the swupdate is already working, I can update the system locally. But when I try to use with hawkbit some erros appears.

[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR corelib/channel_curl.c : channel_get_file : 855 : Cannot initialize sha1 checksum context.

[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR suricatta/server_hawkbit.c : server_hawkbit_error : 174 : No suitable .swu image found

[ERROR] : SWUPDATE failed [0] ERROR suricatta/server_hawkbit.c : server_install_update : 1241 : Error processing update chunk named 'rootfs', version 1.0, part os

I don't understand why isn't working because I can update the system locally with this .swu file using the command "swupdate -i <swu-file>"

I'm trying update my embbeded linux system via suricatta but its not working

Comment: do you have a SSL implementation installed?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by modifying the swupdate configuration (if you installed it yourself) via `make menuconfig` and then enabling `Enable SSL support for image downloading`